# How can I get timer in microsecond in ARMv8 system?

Tags: timer, armv8

I am writing a part of kernel code in ARMv8 RTOS.
I am trying to do a function like gettimeofday() in Linux, which can return system time in second and microsecond.
But I failed to do that.
ARMv8 support PL031, I think it is working at freq. of 1Hz, I cannot get the time in microsecond.
I am NOT sure if I am reading/doing something wrong with PL031, is there any way in ARMv8 to get system time in microsecond?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARMv8 has '**generic timer**' for such a purpose.

You could find description in "ARM Architecture Reference Manual. ARMv8, for ARMv8-A architecture profile" (search for "Generic Timer").

There is also Programmer's Guides for that ([link](https://documentation-service.arm.com/static/600eb3264ccc190e5e68023a?token=))

The catch is that you need to write `CNTFRQ_EL0` register with a system frequency value. This 'frequency' register is not filled by hardware and has limitations of exception level.
But since you doing your RTOS, that should not be an issue.

By reading `CNTPCT_EL0` you could get 'system ticks' that could be, with a help of 'frequency', converted to time.

Comment: Thanks for reply, it is the good idea. And I am wondering if there is a way in ARMv8 (or ARMv8 SOC) to support RTC with microsecond granularity as the gettimeofday returns?

Comment: ARMv8 does not have RTC, as long as I'm aware. SoC might have RTC as an external component, but that's SoC specific and should be checked with manufacturer documentation.

Comment: Sure, that means pl031 is only in 1Hz granularity and generic timer is NOT reporting the time as RTC is (since 1970/01/01), correct?

Comment: generic timer by default count time from powering up moment. Still you could take current time from RTC, convert that to system ticks and write that value to generic timer counter. Since that moment generic timer could be used to report 'current' time with high discretion.

Comment: Yep, that is a good idea to try. Thanks.